# How do I move differentially expressed genes from one matrix to another one?

Tags: r, matrix, data-analysis, data-science

Right now I'm analyzing some data from breast cancer patients and I have a GEO microarray that contains alot of information regarding some genes in the estrogen receptors (columns are genes, rows are their id's and the data is their expression value). I calculated all the p values from each row and adjusted them using the bonferroni method. Right now I have a list of all the ones that have a p value less than my adjusted alpha. The list containts 274 p values from genes that are differentially expressed but I don't need them, I want to take the information (id's with their expression values) from  the original matrix but only from the genes that have a p value smaller than my adjusted alpha from the list of my 274 p values and add them to a new matrix to create a cluster and a heat map to visualize them. I don't know if this is clear enough but in simple terms what I want to do is take the 274 genes from the original matrix and add them to a new one. I tried doing this with a for loop but I'm not that good in R so it's giving me a lot of problems. Here's my (crappy) code.

```
f = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
# all the 1's are genes(columns) resistant to tamoxifen and 0's are genes sensitive to it. 

g <- factor(f)
pvals = rowttests(gEXP,g)$p.value 
# gEXP is the GEO matrix, Here I do a t test for each row and take the p value from each test.

k = 0.05/length(pvals)
list = pvals < k      
# K is the bonferroni adjusted alpha and the how I obtained the 274 p values in my list.

for (ttest in gEXP) {    
    if rowttests(gEXP,g)$p.value < k {     
#I Do a t test for each row and check that it's lower than my adjusted alpha. 

# Now i want to add the genes (from the gEXP matrix, not my list) thathave a p value smaller than alpha to a new matrix (no idea how to do it).
}
```

I hope someone can help me and sorry if I wasn't clear enough as english in not my first language.

Comment: The question is not quite clear. You could improve it by adding some dummy example data and the expected result. I think what you want is to subset the rows from your original matrix into a new one, something like this: `new.matrix = gEXP [ rowttests(gEXP,g)$p.value < k,  ]`

Comment: Wow dude that's exactly what I wanted... It was so easy that I would have never thought of it haha. Thank you!